# Bind_param() on a non-object, cannot locate the reason why it appears

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

## Why it is different

I know what the error means (which is one of the answer listed), but am unable to determine what the cause of the error is. It may be something simple I am overlooking, sometimes these things just require a fresh mind. To digress I have searched this site, and google for 2 days and have viewed several threads that do not provide a satisfactory answer to resolve the issue.

## Image of SQL Table

[image: Table that query is selecting]

## Purpose of Code

User purchases small items from points they acquire by obtaining certain goals. (Ex: Walk 5 miles and get a point). This is basically a table that displays the purchases that the use has made with said points..

## Error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in [DIR OF FILE] on line 137

Line 137

```
$Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->bind_param('ss', $User, $Type);
```

## conn Variable:

It is pulled from a include file [configure.php]

```
//Connect to Database
$conn = new mysqli('SERVER', 'DB USERNAME', 'DB PASSWORD', 'DB TABLE');
```

## Code in Question:

```
$User = $_POST['User'];
        $Type = 'Wellness';

        $Select_Points_Receipt_Query = "SELECT Purchase_Key, Purchase_Amount, Purchase_Item, Purchase_Date From Purchase WHERE Purchase_User = ? AND Purchase_Type = ?";
        $Select_Points_Receipt_stmt = $conn->prepare($Select_Points_Receipt_Query);
        $Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->bind_param('ss', $User, $Type);
        $Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->execute();

        $Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->bind_result($Purchase_Key, $Purchase_Amount, $Purchase_Item, $Purchase_Date);

        echo'<h3>Previous Purchases</h3>';
        echo'<table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Receipt</th>
                    <th>Amount</th>
                    <th>Item</th>
                    <th>Date</th>
                </tr>';
        while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($Select_Points_Receipt_stmt)) 
            {
                echo'<tr>';
                echo'<td>'.$Purchase_Key.'</td>';
                echo'<td>'.$Purchase_Amount.'</td>';
                echo'<td>'.$Purchase_Item.'</td>';
                echo'<td>'.$Purchase_Date.'</td>';
                echo'</tr>';
            }

        echo'</table>';
        echo'<br>';
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: and `$Type` is defined where? all elements named also with no typos, lettercase issues?

Comment: $Type is defined as 'Wellness' (see Second line), and as far as I am aware every element is named.

Comment: my bad. well, non-object may probably mean that your form element isn't named or contains typos, or your query failed. check for errors on both PHP and DB side.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything and change `$Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->execute();` to `if(!$Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$conn->error, E_USER_WARNING);}`

Comment: Thanks I will try that and get back with you.

Comment: I tried that and it gave me the exact same error. I also changed the the $User variable to a string value that I know exists, to rule out the previous form.

Comment: well, check for lettercase for your columns. Wellness and welness with a lowercase "w" may be two different animals. I don't know what else it could be.

Comment: MySQLi should be holding onto an error after the `prepare()` because it is `$Select_Points_Receipt_stmt` which is not an object, meaning prepare failed.  Just before calling `bind_param()` simply check `echo $conn->error;`

Comment: If anything, to really differentiate your question, rewrite it to ask the concrete question you should already be aware of: **Why does mysqli::prepare return false (and how to debug it)?** Strip everything else out.

Comment: Side note - for consistency I'd recommend sticking with the OO-style MySQLi entirely. So instead of using `mysqli_stmt_fetch()` in the while loop, you may use `while ($Select_Points_Receipt_stmt->fetch())`

Comment: Thanks Michael, your suggestion helped me determine the error.. It appears their was a sql query above (one that pulled the amount of points a user has and displayed them) A quick add of $Select_Points_stmt->close(); and I was able to get it resolved.. Apparently, it is pert near impossible to run two queries, and either the extract from the database has to be stored instead of binded, or the query closed before the net one starts..

Comment: @Jason Yes, the old "commands out of sync" error I presume? At least MySQLi's API has improved in recent years to make fetching all rows easier.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, out of sync. Thanks again for the help